# asp.net web service which will consume by android

Tags: asp.net, web-services

I want to create simple android application for CRUD operation. I have sucessfully create this application using PHP and Mysql. but now I want to use asp.net.This is simple webservice

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Services;
using System.Web.Services.Protocols;
using System.Xml.Linq;

[WebService(Namespace = "http://localhost/")]
[WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
// To allow this Web Service to be called from script, using ASP.NET AJAX, uncomment the following line. 
[System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]


public class Service : System.Web.Services.WebService
{
public Service () {

    //Uncomment the following line if using designed components 
    //InitializeComponent(); 
}

[WebMethod]
public string HelloWorld() {
    return "Hello World 124";
}
```

when i try to run this url it gives me error.

```
http://localhost:3541/WebSite3/Service.asmx/HelloWorld
```

**Request format is unrecognized for URL unexpectedly ending in '/HelloWorld'.**

I don't know much about .net. so what I am doning wrong?

what i have to do to run this ???

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a restful webservice so you cannot invoke the methods like that. This is a soap service.

Just invoke this url then it will let you to select your method:
http://localhost:3541/WebSite3/Service.asmx

Then in your android application you can consume it by using [ksoap2-android](https://code.google.com/p/ksoap2-android/) library.

It is not ideal to consume soap services in android. I think you should look at the restful services.

Comment: i am using vs 2008 so can i create restful web service in 2008? if yes can you tell me about toturail??